# TORA Execute Package Procedure with OUT REF CURSOR

Tags: oracle, plsql, tora

I'm trying to execute a Package Procedure that has a couple in parameters and a REF CURSOR out parameter but can't seem to figure it out for [TORA](http://torasql.com/) (my SQL IDE)

Here is a contrived example of a procedure I'd like to execute and see the cursor for:

```
PROCEDURE get_peeps_in_city ( pi_city IN varchar(100), po_recordset OUT REF CURSOR )
    IS
    BEGIN
         OPEN po_recordset
         FOR Select Id, 
                FName, 
                LName
             FROM People
             WHERE City like '%' || pi_city || '%'
    END;
```

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
DECLARE
    v_cursor REF CURSOR;
BEGIN
    execute PKG_PEEPS.get_peeps_in_city('Chicago', v_cursor);
END
```

The error that I get is something along the lines of:

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the
>   following:
>   begin function package pragma procedure subtype type use      form    current
>   cursor

Comment: so what's the question? is there any error?

Comment: seems like you've forgotten semicolon (;) after OPEN cursor

Comment: You can probably ignore any syntax errors, the code is not the same as my production code.  I can guarantee the procedure code works correctly and is syntactically sound because it works for several different applications.  The core of the question is how to call a stored procedure with a ref cursor out parameter from TORA specifically.

Comment: i see... in this case i have no idea)) i've downloaded and installed this software since it's intrested me (i hear about it first from you). it looks cute and comfortable, but for some reason it has crashed after 1 minute of my using it ((

Comment: and btw, what if we omit execute keyword? as i remember it's not necessary in plsql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like this:

```
DECLARE
    v_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
    v_Id NUMBER;
    v_FName VARCHAR2(200);
    v_LName VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
    PKG_PEEPS.get_peeps_in_city('Chicago', v_cursor);

    LOOP
      FETCH v_cursor INTO v_Id, v_FName, v_LName;
      EXIT WHEN v_cursor%NOTFOUND;
        -- do something with v_Id, v_FName, v_LName
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE v_cursor;
END;
/
```

**Update:**

You probably would like that the result of your query is displayed in your IDE as if you had run the SELECT statement directly. This is not going to happen with the above code and I don't know of any code that could achieve that (unless you install a specific table function).

The best thing you can do is output the retrieved data in the loop (using `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`).

Comment: that looks promising... but when I give it a try, I get some new errors about v_cursor ref cursor.  

> PLS-00201: identifier 'CURSOR' must be declared.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that you have to use the old LOOP / FETCH / NOTFOUND / CLOSE thing when using a weakly typed cursor. You might have a strongly typed one. But since your procedure declaration is invalid, I can't tell for sure. Anyway, I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Codo - you can get the results displayed directly in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer, but I can't see how to do it in TOra (and don't know about Toad etc.). You can use `variable v_cursor refcursor`, `exec` the procedure with `:v_cursor` as the out parameter, and then just `print :v_cursor`. The loop/dbms_output looks like the only way to do it in TOra, though.

Comment: That's cool. I didn't know that. But it then is most likely restricted to SQL*Plus and SQL Developer because it's a SQL*Plus command and SQL Developer is the only other tool with a rather complete SQL*plus command implementation.